# Vlookup array function

Tags: arrays, excel, vlookup

I am trying something like this:

```
{=VLOOKUP(A13:D13,[data.xls]Sheet1!$A$162:$H$215,8,FALSE)}
```

**How do I look up an array of values (A11:D13) that look for an exact match array in a table/array?**

So it needs to match A13, B13, C13, D13, in that order and needs an exact match in table lookup to return a value.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Can you add a "helper column" to each sheet??

Comment: Yes.  Both sheets are editable

Answer (score 0):

Try this array formula (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>):

```
=INDEX([data.xls]Sheet1!$H$162:$H$215,MATCH(1,1*ISNUMBER(MATCH([data.xls]Sheet1!$A$162:$A$215,A13:D13,0)),0))
```

Going from inner most:

`MATCH($A$162:$A$215,A13:D13,0)` gets the values from your table that are present among the values that you want to lookup (kind of reverse lookup).

These get converted to `0` and `1` by `1*ISNUMBER()` and then, `MATCH(1, ... ,0)` gets the row number of the first `1`.

`INDEX` just uses it to then return the corresponding value.

Note: This will fetch values that appear first in the range `A13:D13`, meaning that it will not look for `A13` in the column first, but it will look at the first cell in the table if it matches any of `A13:D13`.

---

If you want to check for A13 first:

```
=VLOOKUP(INDEX(A13:D13,MATCH(1,1*ISNUMBER(MATCH(A13:D13,[data.xls]Sheet1!$A$162:$A$215,0)),0)),[data.xls]Sheet1!$A$162:$H$215,2,0)
```

It works on a similar logic, but gets the `INDEX` is now being used to get what value in `A13:D13` appears first in the table array, then uses it for the vlookup.

Answer (score 0):

Since both sheets are editable, rather than making something more complicated, I would add in a "helper column" to both sheets.

So, for example, add in a column BEFORE COLUMN A in your first sheet and put the formula in (here, supposing you're doing so for row 2, but change the row number as needed, obviously):

```
= A2 & "|" & B2 & "|" & C2 & "|" & D2
```

Do the same with your other sheet so you have something to match against, and now you have a single cell value you can use for a regular `VLOOKUP()` function.

Hope this makes sense!

Answer (score 0):

You can try this formula, it only returns a match if you find the 4 A13:D13 values in 4 consecutive rows in A162:A215

```
=INDEX($H$162:$H$212;SUMPRODUCT(MATCH(A13&B13&C13&D13;$A$162:$A$212&$A$163:$A$213&$A$164:$A$214&$A$165:$A$215;0)))
```

Depending on your regional settings you may need to replace arg separator ";" by ","